# Proof of sub field and polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, finite-fields, polynomial-rings

My following task is:

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field und be $\mathbb{K}^{\prime}$ a subfield of $\mathbb{K} . \mathbb{K}[t]$ and $\mathbb{K}^{\prime}[t]$ are polynomial rings over the respective fields in an indefinite. Prove:  $f, g \in \mathbb{K}^{\prime}[t]$ and $q \in \mathbb{K}[t]$ with $f=q g,$ then $q \in \mathbb{K}^{\prime}[t]$ follows.

My idea to prove this is:

A subfield is a subset of a field and it always contains the elements {0,1}. It must also be completed in respect of (+,-,*,:). 
Furthermore, there must be a reciprocal value for each element.

If f,g are elements of K', f,g are also elements of K. If now f = q*g and g={0,1} (because the 0/1 must be in the subfield), then f=q. And since f is in K', q must also be in K'.

Could someone tell me if this is correct and if not, what is missing or wrong, please. Thank you.

Comment: We don't know that $g$ is either $0$ or $1$, though. There are many things it could be.

Comment: Okay. So, what does this mean now?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

We assume that $g\neq 0$, since otherwise the question becomes trivial.

The polynomial ring $\mathbb{K}^{\prime}[t]$ is a Euclidean domain, which means it has a division algorithm: there exist $q_0, r\in \mathbb{K}^{\prime}[t]$ such that $f = q_0 g + r$, with $\deg r < \deg g$. We are given that $f = q g$ with $q\in \mathbb{K}[t]$, so combining these equalities yields
$$
q_0 g + r = q g.
$$
In particular, $g$ divides $r$ in $\mathbb{K}[t]$. Since $\deg r < \deg g$, we must have $r = 0$. Therefore $q_0 g = q g$. Since $g\neq 0$, we have $q = q_0\in \mathbb{K}^{\prime}[t]$.